# Android - Background at bottom

Tags: android, image, layout, background

I should like to have an android app which has its background image on the bottom of the view.
Hopefully this could be achieved by only using XML.

My background image (bg.png) is located at the folder "res/drawable-mdpi".
The XML code is now:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/bg"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="0dip" />
</LinearLayout>
```

But this is stretching the whole image over the whole page. I only want it stretched in horizontal direction.
The height has to be in proportion with the (stretched) width.
And this image has to be the **background** of a view/layout, I want to keep using the layout and add items/objects to it.

I hope someone could help me with this, I've been looking on the internet for it for a few hours and I couldn't find anything more helpful then I have now.

Thanks in advance,

Dennis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly Change your LinearLayout to a RelativeLayout (android:layout_alignParentBottom only works with RelativeLayout).

Secondly use android:src="@drawable/bg" on your ImageView (not background)

Comment: This also doesn't work. Now the image is good-sized (width stretched and the height is in proportion with the width), but this image isn't at the bottom of the app/view. It's vertically centered.

Comment: Difficult to debug from here...try adding scaleType="fitEnd" to your imageview. Does it drop to the bottom then?

Answer (score 0):

if you really want to use the LinearLayout, you can try adding this attribute to your imageview `android:layout_gravity="bottom"`